# Is there a way to manipulate UIImage in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, image, image-processing, uiimageview, uiimage

Is there a way to apply some functions like:brightness,contrast,sharpness,hue,saturation,exposure to uiimages. For example I have a UIImageview and inside that i have a uiimage. I want to manipulate its brightness or contrast or sharpness with a help of UISlider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the sample app [GLImageProcessing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html), however it uses openGL to do the image processing, but it is really fast.